# Make a thread to wait until button is clicked

Tags: c#

For the context: I want to start at the "same time" an EMG and a camera.

It looks like this:

```
Public class EMG
{
 public void startemg()
  {
    EMG emg = new EMG();
    emg.Initialize();  //takes a lot of time 

    emg.Start();
   [...]
   }
}
```

And then I start the camera and the EMG when I click on a button:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            Task t = new Task(EMG.startemg);
            Task t1 = new Task(Camera.start)
            t.Start();
            t1.Start();

        }
```

My big issue here is  initialiazing the EMG take quite a long time (several seconds..) So there is a big gap between the  my camera and EMG 's acquisition start. Then i would like to start the `emg.Start()`  & the `Camera.start` at "the same time".

I don't want to put `camera.start` on my EMG class.

I tried to separate `emg.initialize` and `emg.RecordStart`  in two separate void but it's impossible It only works if they are both in the same void with `EMG emg = new EMG();`.

I cant' put an `await task.run` with emg.start

The best way would be to start EMG class before, make it wait just before the  `emg.start` until I click on the button . Make this thread wait and start it back dynamically with the button.

Or maybe make `t1` to start when `emg.initialize` is finished would be easier.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try use a WaitHandler like ManulResetEvent for synchronization. I'm guessing it is important the the same thread calls Initialize and Start on the EMG.

```
public class EMG
{
  private ManualResetEvent waitHandler = new ManualResetEvent(false);

  public void Initialize()
  {
    EMG emg = new EMG();
    emg.Initialize();  //takes a lot of time 
    waitHandler.WaitOne();
    emg.Start();
  }

  public void Start()
  {
     waitHandler.Set();
  }
}
```

---

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
  Task cameraTask = new Task(Camera.start)
  cameraTask .Start();
  EMG.Start();
}
```

Comment: Exactly the kind of code i need thank you. Little issue though it said "MAnualResetEvent does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments." ... Don't know how to resolve that :s

Comment: You should maybe also look into cancellationTokens in order to stop it again in case the button is never clicked?

Comment: I add a messagebox.show("²²") just before the waithandler.WaitOne
I make it initialiaze the "²²" shows up and after i click on the button. Wierd thing after it finished the ²² come back and the EMG start again. Any idea why?

Comment: I change Manual to AutoResetEvent, the messagebox come a second time (why?????) but the emg doesnt run a second time.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... try the following

```
public class EMG
{
  // Local variable
  EMG emg = new EMG();

  // Task to hod init process
  Task cameraInitTasks;

  public EMG():base()
  {
    InitMyOtherStuff(); // Other init code

    // Create your task on class initialization
    cameraInitTasks = new Task(EMG.startemg);

    // Start it
    cameraInitTasks.Start();

  }

  public button2_Click()
  {
     // jic, wait until task finished
     cameraInitTasks.Wait();

     // This one should take little time, right?
     emg.Start();

     // Go and take the picture
     DoPictureTake()
  }
  ...
}
```

Not tested but should work